# compareTo type error

Tags: scala, types, compareto

I've tried to make a generic function `diff` which calculate gaps on a target vector(`Array[T]`)

e.g.

diff(Array(1, 3, 5)) -> Array(2, 2)
diff(Array(Date(2018-01-01), Date(2018-01-03), Date(2018-01-06))) -> Array(2, 3)

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

object Test extends App {

  val toDate: String => Date =
    (x: String) => new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(x).asInstanceOf[Date]

  val data: Array[Date] = 
    Array("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-10").map(toDate(_))

  def diff[E <: Comparable[_]](xs: Array[E]): Array[Int] =
    if(xs.length < 2) Array(0)
    else xs.tail.zipWithIndex.map { tu =>
      val x2: E = tu._1
      val idx: Int = tu._2
      val x1: E = xs.init(idx)
      x2 compareTo x1
    }

  (data).foreach(println(_))
  diff(data).foreach(println(_))
}
```

There occurs an error like this,

> Error:(19, 20) type mismatch;
>   found: x1.type (with underlying type E)
>   required: _$1  x2 compareTo x1

since `x2` & `x1` are type `E` which are sort of `Compareable[_]`

I don't know how to fix my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve to your problem is using view bound:

```
object Test extends App {

    val toDate: String => java.sql.Date =
(x: String) => new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(x).getTime)

    val data: Array[Date] =
Array("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-10").map(toDate(_))

    def diff[E <% Comparable[_ >: E]](xs: Array[E]): Array[Int] =
    if (xs.length < 2) Array(0)
    else xs.tail.zipWithIndex.map { tu =>
       val x2: E = tu._1
       val idx: Int = tu._2
       val x1: E = xs(idx)
       x2 compareTo x1
    }


   data.foreach(println(_))
   diff(data).foreach(println(_))
}
```

which i learn from [How do I write the equivalent of T extends Comparable?](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10622).

By the way, compareTo doesn't return the difference between two elements. It only returns -1, 0 and 1.

Comment: @Curycu My pleasure:-)